# Alternative to large "if-else" tree algorithm?

Tags: python

brand new here, and fairly new to programming. I have written a program in Python that summarizes or "compresses" large UV-Vis absorbance data sets commonly encountered in chemistry and physics. I am trying to add the final touches to the program by making sections more "Pythonic". The following snippet is one such example.

```
while j < (N):
    j=j+1
    B=A[1+(10*j)+R][1:k] #Extraction expression.
    C=[float(i) for i in B] #Float conversion.
    D[0].append(C[0]),D[1].append(C[1]),D[2].append(C[2])
    if NC >= 4:
        D[3].append(C[3])
        if NC >= 5:
            D[4].append(C[4])
            if NC >= 6:
                D[5].append(C[5])
                if NC >= 7:
                    D[6].append(C[6])
                    if NC >= 8:
                        D[7].append(C[7])
                        if NC >= 9:
                            D[8].append(C[8])
                            if NC >= 10:
                                D[9].append(C[9])
                                if NC >= 11:
                                    D[10].append(C[10])
                                    if NC == 12:
                                        D[11].append(C[11])
```

C is a nested list. I am trying to append the index-specific elements contained within the lists inside C.

I.e. C = [[A1, B1, C1],[A2, B2, C2],[A3, B3, C3],...] 
-- > [A1, A2, A3,...An], [B1, B2, B3,...Bn],...

The problem is that if NC is equivalent to some index N, the indices of the nested lists are of the same index, and the append algorithm is different for each value of NC.

The above snippet works perfectly for my purposes, however as the program evolves, the length and duplicate code is not feasible long term.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note first of all that it's not necessary to nest them; if `NC >= x`, you know it's also going to be `>= x - 1`. That means you can "flatten" your tree to look like this:

```
while j < (N):
    j=j+1
    B=A[1+(10*j)+R][1:k] #Extraction expression.
    C=[float(i) for i in B] #Float conversion.
    D[0].append(C[0]),D[1].append(C[1]),D[2].append(C[2])
    if NC >= 4:
        D[3].append(C[3])
    if NC >= 5:
        D[4].append(C[4])
    if NC >= 6:
        D[5].append(C[5])
    if NC >= 7:
        D[6].append(C[6])
    if NC >= 8:
        D[7].append(C[7])
    if NC >= 9:
        D[8].append(C[8])
    if NC >= 10:
        D[9].append(C[9])
    if NC >= 11:
        D[10].append(C[10])
    if NC == 12:
        D[11].append(C[11])
```

Now in any situation where you're just doing the same thing over and over again with slightly different values, you can use a loop:

```
while j < (N):
    j=j+1
    B=A[1+(10*j)+R][1:k] #Extraction expression.
    C=[float(i) for i in B] #Float conversion.
    D[0].append(C[0]),D[1].append(C[1]),D[2].append(C[2])
    for i in range(4, 12):
        if NC >= i:
            D[i - 1].append(C[i - 1])
    if NC == 12:
        D[11].append(C[11])
```

EDIT: I know you mentioned that this is working for your purposes, but be aware of what happens for the case when `NC > 12`. That means you will append to everything *up to but not including* `D[11]`. If that's what you want, then you're golden. But if that last comparison is really supposed to be `>=` rather than `==`, then you can of course just write the program as

```
    for i in range(4, 13):
        if NC >= i:
            D[i - 1].append(C[i - 1])
```

Without that extra `if NC == 12` at the end.

Comment: Ahh yes, works perfectly and I see what you did. NC will not actually cross 12 because essentially the spectrophotometer we are using reads 12 by 8 microplates. However your edit actually makes me realize that there are microplates that have dimensions greater than 12 by 8. Food for thought!

Comment: very glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

First, in each iteration, you're appending values to a range of `D`. Instead of hard-coding the range as a ladder of `if` statements, you can just loop the right amount. That's `xrange(max(3, min(12, NC)))` but if you can assume that `NC <= 12` then this can be simplified further to simply `xrange(max(3, NC))`.

Secondly, you're doing a lot of work to transform `A` into `B` and then `C`, but using each value once. Instead, you can just fold the computation into the place where the value is used.

Thirdly, you don't initialize `j`, but assuming it starts at `0`, the `while j < N` loop can be simplified to a `for` loop.

Putting that together:

```
for j in xrange(1, N+1):
    for i in xrange(max(3, min(12, NC))):
        D[i].append(float(A[2 + 10*j + R])
```

[Note: untested, so there may be lingering off-by-one errors].

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using a load of nested if functions, use a while loop and reduce the NC value each turn whilst the value is >= 4:

```
import math
NC_floor = int(math.floor(NC))

while NC_floor >= 4:
    NC_floor -= 1
    D[NC_floor].append(NC_floor)
```